# Wrapping a void * argument in Python SWIG

Tags: python, c, swig, void-pointers

I am wrapping this lib with Python SWIG that has a function looking like this:

```
int set_option(Foo *foo, const char *name, void *value);
```

In the lib `const char *name` is mapped to a type that I have access to look up: `int`, `char *`, `char **`.

The wrapper code generated by default accepts only a wrapped `void *` (naturally).

What is the best way to make the wrapped method accept **any** Python object as argument, and do the type checking, and Python to C conversion in my own C code?

My guess would be some kind of type map, but alas I cannot figure it out.

@Goodies

```
In [12]: lib.set_option(foo, "option", "value")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4ccf706b5c50> in <module>()
----> 1 lib.set_option(foo, "option", "value")

TypeError: in method 'set_option', argument 3 of type 'void *'
```

Comment: I'm probably not understanding this correctly, but don't you generally take a PyObject pointer as an argument and parse the arguments in C? It shouldn't accept a specific object by default afaik. New to CPython, though.

Comment: Mind posting that in OP? It's tough to see in the comments.

Comment: @Goodies: Yes, formatting is not well in comment.

Comment: This is perpendicular to the concept of SWIG. SWIG is meant for exposing types and avoid type-less interfaces. What you could do is create an interface and inherit from that. You could use an enumeration to distinguish different implementations.

Comment: @JensMunk What I have done right now is to make set_option_<type> methods in C that SWIG wraps. It just requires more work in the Python code. Like check type of name and call the proper method. Is that what you are referring to as well?

Comment: One option would be to make a multi-argument typemap that accepts a sequence of two values such as `(name,value)`. The input typemap could check that the first item is a string, lookup the type, check and translate the second value, then call your function.  If you don't like calling the function from Python as `set_option(foo,(name,value))` you can add a thin `%pythoncode` wrapper to give it the interface you want.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Now that is more what I like! I will try it out. I might ask you about some specifics, since I am not a typemap wizard yet.

Comment: I might find time to write up an example this evening if no one has answered yet.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I think I got it. I had to include the `Foo *` in the typemap too, since it holds the type information. If you feel like it, make an example and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: If you figured it out, go ahead and post it as an answer.  It's acceptable to do that :)

Comment: You can make SWIG functions that accept PyObject inputs, e.g. using `%extend` or `%inline` and they do behave exactly how you'd hope. I think that would extend to a `%apply` too. I can maybe write something up later if that strikes your fancy.

Comment: @Flexo: That would be nice if you could. Then I wouldn't have to wrap the python method to untuple the arguments in my current implementation. And it would teach me more about SWIG, things I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to pass a `PyObject` to something using `%extend` you can modify what you've got and simply write the following:

```
%extend Foo {
    int set_option(const char *name, PyObject *value) {
            // Here value is now a PyObject *, so work with that.
            // $self is Foo *foo
            return 0;
    }
};
```

There's no need for a typemap and this function now accepts any Python input. What you do with it is up to you and if you retain the object you'll need increase the reference count.

Comment: Yes, that is all I want to do. I wasn't aware that SWIG allowed that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was rather simple. I wanted `value` as `PyObject *` so I could type check and convert it myself. Here is the function i wanted to wrap:

```
int set_option(Foo *foo, const char *name, void *value);
```

This solution also makes it a method of `class Foo`.

```
%extend Foo {
        int set_option(const char *name, void *value) {
                // Here value is now a PyObject *, so work with that.
                // $self is Foo *foo
                return 0;
        }
};

%typemap(in) (void *value) {
        $1 = (void *) $input;
};
```

Comment: I think you'll have a reference counting problem here, depending on what you do inside set_option, so you'll want a Py_INCREF($input) in the in typemap and a way to arrange for disposing of them later

Comment: I don't think so in my case. I merely extract the information in C and make a copy of it. I don't keep reference to any data owned by a Python object.

Comment: I cannot post my real code because of non-disclosure.

Comment: Can we use PyLong_AsVoidPtr instead of the cast in the typemap?
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsVoidPtr