# Type checking and overloaded methods in SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ method that can be called as `x(const std::string &a, bool b=true)` or as `x(const SomeClass &object, bool b=true)`.

In Python, I can call the SWIG wrappers with `x('Hello', True)` and `x('Hello')` and `x(someObject, True)`.

However, if I try something like `x('Hi', 'Hello')` swig doesn't convert 'Hello' to a bool, so I get a `NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function`.

How can I tell it to convert the second argument to bool if present?

--- Update ------------------------------------------------------

https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/CHANGES#L1527-L1581

The above link seems to suggest this is now the desired behaviour, although it can 'of course' be changed with a typemap...?

Comment: In your C++ code, the call to `X(const std::string&, bool)` with `x("Hi", "Hello")` would work because *string-literals* are implicitly convertible to `bool`. SWIG doesn't take this into account, and shouldn't. Add a correct overload of `X(const std::string&, const std::string&)` and generate your bindings again..

Comment: The point is that the second argument, in a Python program, should be allowed to be _anything_ for which `if(b):` would hold. I can't add a correct overload for every possible type!

Comment: I think I understand your problem now. What about writing a custom "typemap" and applying it to that specific function signature. Or [extending it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257318/1621391)

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can see typemaps only address single arguments, so you can't match it to a specific signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I fixed it like this (may have consequences...):

```
#if defined(SWIGPYTHON)
    %typemap(typecheck,precedence=SWIG_TYPECHECK_BOOL) bool { $1 = 1; }
    %typemap(in) bool { $1=PyObject_IsTrue($input); }
#endif
```

The first typemap tells swig that everything can be treated as a bool, in Python. 
The second one, from @flexo's answer, converts the matched argument to a C++ bool.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a typemap for SWIG that calls the Python Object protocol function `PyObject_IsTrue` for any input like this:

```
%module test
%typemap(in) bool b "$1=PyObject_IsTrue($input);"
void foobar(bool b=true);
```